# Format the ExifTool output of a filename list from an -if statement

Tags: output, filenames, exiftool

I am running this command to display a list of files with a value of "rotate" contained in the -Orientation tag:

exiftool -if "$orientation =~ /rotate/i" -orientation *.jpg

The output I get is a list like:

```
======== 08.08.20 WYC Races-232.jpg
Orientation                     : Rotate 270 CW
======== 08.08.20 WYC Races-247.jpg
Orientation                     : Rotate 270 CW
======== 08.08.20 WYC Races-268.jpg
Orientation                     : Rotate 270 CW
  135 files failed condition
   45 image files read
```

What I want as output is simply a list of filenames:

```
08.08.20 WYC Races-232.jpg
08.08.20 WYC Races-247.jpg
08.08.20 WYC Races-268.jpg
```

I know I can pipe the output to "FIND /I "=======" to select just the filename line but I would prefer to modify ExifTool's output to just list the filename.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Sailor Guy

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you just want files listed which contain case-insensitive "Rotate" in their *"orientation"* tag:

```
exiftool -p '$filename' -if '$orientation =~ /Rotate/i' *jpg 2> /dev/null
```